# Can celery wait until enough resource (RAM) is available?

Tags: python, redis, parallel-processing, celery, task-queue

I have a program that does heavy computations on big images and obviously it can only process so many requests that the system's RAM allow.

I use Celery+Redis for queuing these long tasks and wonder if there is any way to instruct Celery to check for RAM availability first before starting a new task (but keep them queued nonetheless)? Some type of lock that will open after RAM is freed by a finished task?

I would be happy with any suggestion or direction to look in.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using [celery inspect](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#management-command-line-utilities-inspect-control)

to retrieve the cluster status, and overall memory occupation.

in combination with [retry or ack late](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry)

#### the idea

When the task starts, can query the cluster (or an external service) to retrieve all memory occupation info:

```
# example
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(...)
app.control.inspect().active()
```

It returns a lot of information for each worker available.

After that, you should apply some kind of memory-based rules and proceed with the computation or decide to posticipate the processing:

```
# example
@celery.task(bind=True)
def task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if is_there_enought_memory():
        do_stuff()
    else:
        time.sleep(...)
        self.retry(...)
```

When the minimum requirements are not satisfied, the task waits a certain amount of time and reschedule the task itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. with your solution, It seems like when the memory is freed from one task, multiple tasks from the queue will start to process although resources are enough for only one. is that correct? There must be some type of lock so that only celery knows exactly how many tasks to start.

Comment: The task will be processed again only from one  task. and again it will check for memory availability

Comment: actually multiple tasks will be started. Upon starting a task the memory required for it is not just fully booked for it. memory usage changes during the task execution time, depending on what is being computed. Example: each task has 3 steps and needs 5GB maximum (lets assume only step 2 requires 5GB). is_there_enought_memory() will return True to multiple tasks and will be all started but then each one of them at step 2 will want 5GB and the program will crash.

Comment: If the memory occupation is an atomic task, and cannon be estimated so in a concurrent environment this canon be avoided. Otherwise if you can estimate occupation or the process can be interrupted, it seems be possible to recover it  later using .retry().